# Find and replace a string specified in double quotes conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a long string, lets say a part of it is: 

`signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: \"123\")`

I want to replace the value stored against the key `password` which is `"123"` with a obfuscated text like `---hidden---`, for logging purposes, as this is a sensitive information.
What can be the most efficient possible way of identifying and replacing the aforementioned string?

Comment: since it sounds like it would only run once when the password is submitted its not good to worry much about efficience. Just use what works and it will be fine.

Comment: Is this some kind of log? If so, the `signin` can have some prefix data (like a timestamp for example)? Or would the line always start with `signin`?

Comment: Its graphql way of making signin request to server. At-least for the project that I am working on.

Comment: So, on that line there's some more data preceding `signin`keyword. Does that data is variable in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`(?<=password:\s)\\".*\\"(?=\))`

[Example Tests](https://regexr.com/3uemt)

```
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: \"123\")
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: \"supersecreetPassword123\")
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: \"123w453457634\")
```

Replacing it, turning into:

```
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: --hidden--)
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: --hidden--)
signin(email: \"haroon@gmial.com\", password: --hidden--)
```

Talking about performance, you can check [this online test](https://regex101.com/r/iuamsD/1) using about *~14000* lines, and just took about ~562ms to match them all